# Angular form dropdown 1 used to select option in dropdown 2

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, dropdown

I have two dropdown menus in an Angular form. One is country and the other is country dialing code. When the user selects USA on the first dropdown, I want to update the second dropdown to default to +1 for the dialing code. Otherwise, the second dropdown should deafult to the placeholder "Select Country Code". I have successfully done this using javascript, but Angular still considers the form to be invalid when submitted. I've tried forcing the field to become valid in the javascript, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this using javascript or an ng command in the HTML? I would like to keep the html formatted as is (i.e. with the select and options tags).

HTML:

```
<select required
class="form-control vertical-gap-5--bottom color-gray--warm-8"
id="country" name="country" type="text"
ng-model="contactSession.country">
<option data-countryCode="UG" value="256">Uganda</option>
<option data-countryCode="UA" value="380">Ukraine</option>
<option data-countryCode="AE" value="971">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">United Kingdom</option>
<option data-countryCode="US" value="1">United States</option>
<option data-countryCode="UY" value="598">Uruguay</option>
<option data-countryCode="UZ" value="998">Uzbekistan</option>
</select>

<select required
class="form-control vertical-gap-5--bottom color-gray--warm-8"
id="countryCode" name="countryCode" type="text"
ng-init="contactSession.countryCode = '1'"
ng-model="contactSession.countryCode">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Country Code</option>
<option data-countryCode="UA" value="380">Ukraine (+380)</option>
<option data-countryCode="AE" value="971">United Arab Emirates(+971)</option>
<option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">United Kingdom (+44)</option>
<option data-countryCode="US" id="usaSelection" value="1">United States (+1)</option>
<option data-countryCode="UY" value="598">Uruguay (+598)</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
    $('select[name=country]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        document.getElementById("countryCode").value = document.getElementById("usaSelection").value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("countryCode").value = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128534/ng-options-set-ng-model-value-as-selected-item-in-blank-list/46129425#46129425)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: did you check the demo?

Comment: The demo shows an entirely new dropdown being rendered with new values. I want to keep the same dropdown, just autoselect a value within that dropdown when the first dropdown selection is USA. The form becomes invalid when I do this with the javascript shown above.

Comment: Why do you want to maintain HTML? What I want to suggest is using 'ng-options' in `select`. And did you understand about 'Angularjs' enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdown depends on other dropdown - angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849859/dropdown-depends-on-other-dropdown-angularjs)

Comment: I understand the use of ng-options, but I don't think it is useful in this case. I only want to have the country code default to +1 when the user selects United States, but they should have the option to change the country code to another value if they like. ng-options will link all the values

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle, but I am not sure whether this is same as your intent or not.

[Change select box](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/15ed4kmy/2/)

```
<select ng-options="country.code as country.nameAndCode for country in countries"
        ng-model="selectedCountryAndCode"
        ng-change="changeCountryAndCode();"
        required>
    <option value="">Select Country Code</option>
</select>
```

If you use 'ng-options', it'll make code more simple.

.

.

**UPDATE**

[Here's updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/15ed4kmy/3/).

A little modified following as I've understood.

.

.

.

**Latest UPDATE**

[Here's another updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/15ed4kmy/7/)

Comment: I feel as though this is close, however the Country Code should remain on the option "Select Country Code", and only change when the user selects United States. And after this happens, the user should be able to change the country code without it affecting the country. It is only supposed to default to +1 when the user selects United States as a convenience.

Comment: It seems that ng-options binds every value together, however a user should be able to live in the USA, but select a country code that is outside of the USA.

Comment: @display___ Ah, I think I've caught up with your intent a little. So you mean when user select a country, a country code is given by selected country. But  if user select a country code, country code will change but country is still same as user selected, right?

Comment: I've created a fiddle of the exact behavior the form requires, which I have achieved. When USA is selected, the country code changes, but a user can change the country code and country will remain on USA. The problem is, when updating the fields value using jQuery, the form does not become valid. A user has to manually make a selection to make that field valid. How can I validate the the country code field when it is pragmatically selected? https://jsfiddle.net/___display/vv9dsajm/3/

Comment: @display___ why do you wanna validating using 'JQuery'? It's a kind of bad way using 'AngularJS' and 'JQuery' together. There are many good ways using 'form' in 'AngularJS'. If you could agree with my suggestion, I'll try to make another fiddle more similar with yours.

Comment: The rest of my form validation is performed using Angular, but since I couldn't get the behavior described above I tried using jQuery. If you could assist with a new fiddle, that would be great

Comment: @display___ sorry bro! Now I've started other work, so I will make this on this weekend. And I'll post a new fiddle whether you already solve this.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Angular?

Comment: @display___ Sorry pal, I'm too late. I've just brought another fiddle! My busy time is almost gone. So now I can have time for checking your question again. Even though my answers can not be gonna great helpful for you. :)